# Access 2013, want to make sure my SQL is doing what I think it is

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

My understanding is that the following SQL is:

(1) Taking data from tbl1 and updating tbl2

(2) Both adding new records and updating old ones.

(3) Overwriting existing data in tbl2

(4) NOT overwriting data in tbl2 with blank cells

Am I off the mark on this one and if so how?

```
UPDATE tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 
ON tbl1.thing0 = tbl2.thing0 
SET tbl2.[thing1] = tbl1.[thing1], tbl2.[thing2] = tbl1.[thing2], tbl2.[thing3] = tbl1.[thing3];
```

EDIT1

So to satisfy conditions 2 and 4 and keep it easy on users:

(2) Use an APPEND query to add new rows of data, the UPDATE will only change existing rows.

**(4) With the Update Query, how can I prevent it from overwriting data in existing rows with blank cells?**

I have users on-site updating a table in real time and worry that remote users updating the table once they have a connection will overwrite the on-site users data with a bunch of blank cells.

Will something like this satisfy condition 4?

```
UPDATE tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 
ON tbl1.thing0 = tbl2.thing0 
SET tbl2.[thing1] = tbl1.[thing1], tbl2.[thing2] = tbl1.[thing2], tbl2.[thing3] = tbl1.[thing3]
WHERE Not Null:
```

(5) Then attach a macro to a command button so users can run both queries at the same time.

Comment: You have typos on SET row? db2 means tbl2 etc?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes
2. no - UPDATE doesn't add records; your query updates all records in tbl2, where corresponding record(s) in tbl1 can be found
3. yes
4. no - if corresponding row/record in tbl1 has empty/blank fields, then these will be written into tbl2 anyway

After OP edits, Re #4:

You can use Iif() on SET line, like next (maybe you should add Trim() or check for NULL values or similar):

```
SET tbl2.[thing1] = Iif(tbl1.[thing1] = '', tbl2.[thing1], tbl1.[thing1])
```

Iif() is MS Access function; in proper SQL you have to use Case statement.

Comment: Actually 1. is "No"  (1) Taking data from tbl1 and updating tbl2.  It is updating tbl1.

Comment: @SQLDBA - this is not SQL, but MS Access :) What means that it can update any joined table; looking at SET line reveals that fields in tbl2 are updated.

Comment: Strangely, that makes sense.  Thanks for the clarification.